# Modal not opening with link click

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

This is my first time working with modals and I'm having trouble getting my modal to open on a link click. I'm receiving no errors in the console so I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this.

**HTML:**

```
<!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>Earthquake Feed</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#simpleModal" data-target="simpleModal" data-toggle ="simpleModal" id="aboutModal">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Legend</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--About Modal-->
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <p>Hello....I am a modal</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Get about modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
// get open about modal link
var aboutModal = document.getElementById('aboutModal');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// listen for open/close click
aboutModal.addEventListener('click', openModal);
aboutModal.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// opens and closes modal
function openModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}
function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what exacly is the problem?

Comment: When I click the About link the modal does not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind both the open and close function to the same button. So when you click it, the browser will open and close the modal at the same time, so it looks like nothing happened. Just bind it to the correct button.

Also, add a default state of closed to the modal.

```js
// Get about modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
// get open about modal link
var aboutModal = document.getElementById('aboutModal');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// listen for open/close click
aboutModal.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// opens and closes modal
function openModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'block';
}
function closeModal(){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#simpleModal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>Earthquake Feed</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li>
      <a href="#simpleModal" data-target="simpleModal" data-toggle ="simpleModal" id="aboutModal">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Legend</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--About Modal-->
<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
    <p>Hello....I am a modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your aboutModal has two different callbacks - openModal() and closeModal() for the same click event. When you click aboutModal, openModal() displays your modal but after that, closeModal() hides it as both of them execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `openModal()` to `aboutModal` and your `closeModal` on click handler to `closeBtn`. By adding both of these to `aboutModal` both of these get invoked. Clicking `aboutModal` executes `openModal()` first then immediately executes `closeModal` right after. See the snippet.

```js
// Get about modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
// get open about modal link
var aboutModal = document.getElementById('aboutModal');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// listen for open/close click
aboutModal.addEventListener('click', openModal);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// opens and closes modal
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  modal.style.display = 'none'
})
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h4>Earthquake Feed</h4>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#simpleModal" data-target="simpleModal" data-toggle="simpleModal" id="aboutModal">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Legend</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!--About Modal-->
<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
    <p>Hello....I am a modal</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding both the open and close `click` events on `aboutModal`, due to which the function for closing the modal overdoes the work done by function for opening modal.
You need to add the `closeModal` event function on `closeBtn`.

```
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly the problem (looking at your code) is that you created 2 click listeners, one with an open function and another with a close function.

I'll modify your code chaging the functions to a toggle:

```js
// Get about modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
// get open about modal link
var aboutModal = document.getElementById('aboutModal');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// listen for toggle Modal
aboutModal.addEventListener('click', toggleModal);

// opens and closes modal
function toggleModal(){
    modal.style.display = (modal.style.display = 'block')? 'none' : 'block';
}
```